# Bootstrap media object issue on css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to use Bootstrap to display media(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/),like the first one in the website,but after copy-pasting the code from docu,the results are not the same.The external bootstrap_part.css is empty.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap_part.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://toert.github.io/Isolated-Bootstrap/versions/4.0.0-beta/iso_bootstrap4.0.0min.css">
    <title>Harli Lacej - Website</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../personal-website/img/H.png" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <img src="./img/profile_photo.png" alt="profile_photo" height="150px" width="150px">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="bootstrap">
           <div class="media">
        <img class="mr-3" src="img/img_asd.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="60">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
          Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

...

Comment: could you please use the links in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/ (Quick start section)

Comment: the problem stays that i want only a part of website to use bootstrap that's why I choose the link from Github that isolates bootstrap to not affect the other part of script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.The error was code provided in Github.Anyone who wants isolated Bootstrap 4.1.0 can use this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://toert.github.io/Isolated-Bootstrap/versions/4.1.0/iso_bootstrap4.1.0min.css">
```

Others work same as written here:https://github.com/toert/Isolated-Bootstrap